# jsonfield queryset and filtering

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to search through the contents of this `JSONField`:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    data = models.JSONField()
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length = 32, unique = True)
    prod = models.ForeignKey("product", on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True)
```

where the `data` looks like this:

```
{"name": "monkey", "price": 22, "description": "text here", "imgb64": "bkmocdnm32iojo3d0..."}
```

I want to search via the product_data attributes within the `JSONField`.

I tried:

```
Test.objects.filter(product__data__in = "monkey")
```

or

```
Test.objects.filter(product__data__name__icontains = "monkey")
```

but both result in `<QuerySet []`.

Additionally, is it possible to search through **some** of the keys of `data`? Or even better, exclude some keys when searching?